# Can an aggregate function be in SOQL where clause?

Tags: soql, aggregate, documentation

Can an aggregate function be in SOQL where clause?
Looks like it cannot but I can't find anywhere a documentation a clear answer if it is forbidden and why if it is

Comment: The more details you provide, particularly code you've written to provide an example of what you're asking, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation around the [HAVING](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm) clause.

Example:

```
SELECT Account.Owner.Name
FROM Opportunity
GROUP BY Account.Owner.Name
HAVING COUNT(Id) > 100
```

Comment: Yes, I know about Having, I wonder why we can't just query SELECT Account.Owner.Name
FROM Opportunity where COUNT(Id) > 100

Comment: @XpucTuHKaBuwuBaHKa HAVING applies to "groups" of rows, while WHERE applies to "individual" rows. This is how standard SQL works, and SOQL is a subset of this.

Comment: This is one of the really obscure questions that can absolutely nail someone taking a certification exam when they've never run across a situation where they needed to create a query like the one above.